# Unable to get SwiftData to store/retrieve CGPoint, CGSize, CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, codable, swift-data

I'm trying to get SwiftData to store Core Graphics base structures like CGSize, CGRect, CGPoint, but it doesn't work. I suppose CGVector and CGAffineTransform could be added to the list, but I haven't tried.

My question: What is a smart way to make SwiftData store/retrieve CG-structs?

This is what I have found:
All the CG-structs conform to Codable through conformance to Encodable and Decodable. However, they all use unkeyed encoding. Unkeyed encoding will get the simple class below to cause a crash with `Fatal error: Composite Coder only supports Keyed Container`.

```swift
@Model
class TestCGSize {
    // Fatal error: Composite Coder only supports Keyed Container
    var cgSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero

    init(cgSize: CGSize) { self.cgSize = cgSize }
}
```

Side note: The fatal error message is not entirely true as CGFloat works and CGFloat uses unkeyed encoding.

How can the problem be solved?

*Write an extension for Codable:* Can't override an existing implementation of Encodable/Decodable with a new extension.

*Write a subclass:* Can't subclass a struct.

*Write a @propertyWrapper:* Will generate a compiler error: `Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property`. It seems SwiftData makes all properties into computed properties.

*Use didSet observer*: It actually works but only one-way. SwiftData will create the columns in the database and store the values, but I can only get retrieval to work partially. See test code below.

*Write a wrapper struct:* Starting on my first attempt. Any working example will be highly appreciated.

There is probably another approach I haven't thought of. I will be grateful for any help.

```swift
@Model
class TestCGSize {
    @Transient
    var cgSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero {
        didSet {
            cgSizeWidth = cgSize.width
            cgSizeHeight = cgSize.height
        }
    }
    
    // Columns created and data stored in db.
    // Data retrieved, but cgSize not updated
    var cgSizeWidth: Double = 0 {
        didSet { cgSize.width = cgSizeWidth }
    }
    var cgSizeHeight: Double = 0 {
        willSet { cgSize.height = newValue }
    }
    
    init(cgSizeWidth: Double, cgSizeHeight: Double) {
        self.cgSizeWidth = cgSizeWidth
        self.cgSizeHeight = cgSizeHeight
        self.cgSize.width = cgSizeWidth
        self.cgSize.height = cgSizeHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: Make cgSize a computed property (get and set) and cgSizeWidth/height private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Transient` creates a second source of truth. You can keep a single source of truth by turning `cgSize` into a computed property with a `get` and `set`.

Then for continuity sake you can make the database properties `private`.

```
import SwiftData
@Model
class TestCGSize {
    var cgSize: CGSize {
        get {
            .init(width: _cgSizeWidth, height: _cgSizeHeight)
        }
        set {
            self._cgSizeWidth = newValue.width
            self._cgSizeHeight = newValue.height
        }
    }
    
    // Columns created and data stored in db.
    private var _cgSizeWidth: Double = 0.0
    private var _cgSizeHeight: Double = 0.0
    
    init(cgSize: CGSize) {
        self.cgSize = cgSize
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work fine in my tests. Now I just need to get it wrapped in a macro to remove the boilerplate code and avoid typos.

Comment: @HighFive I don’t think you can use a macro in a macro, transformable might be a better option

Comment: Using @Attribute(.transformable(by: ValueTransformer)) to enable the transformer? I don't think a ValueTransformer can be used with structs. Probably why 'matt' suggested to use NSValue to wrap the CG-struct, as NSValue is a class and conforms to NSSecureCoding.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what NSValue is for. It wraps a CG-type in something that is secure codable.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue

The CoreData way would be to put a value transformer between the value and the database, and I presume SwiftData would therefore allow you to do the same thing.